# Entity Framework Performance issue with Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to know which one has the **better performance** ?

```
 var allocations = 
        Catalog.ResourceAllocations
               .Where(c => c.Pet.Key == petKey && c.Pet.Owner.Key == ownerKey)
               .Include(k => k.Appointment)
               .Include(k => k.Service)
               .Include(k => k.Appointment.Provider.Address)
               .ToList();
```

**OR**

```
var allocations = 
       Catalog.ResourceAllocations
              .Where(c => c.Pet.Key == petKey && c.Pet.Owner.Key == ownerKey)
              .Include(k => k.Appointment.Provider.Address)
              .Include(k => k.Service)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried to run both queries?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes.Out put is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation for [`DbQuery<T>.Include(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.include%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) states that (please read **NOTES** at the end - it describes how path including works):

> Paths are all-inclusive. For example, if an include call indicates
>   Include("Orders.OrderLines"), not only will OrderLines be included,
>   but also Orders.

So `k.Appointment.Provider.Address` will include `k.Appointment` anyway. Even if there is no performance hit, second query is better, because it does not contain duplicate include definitions.

**UPDATE:** There will be no performance difference in database query, because both LINQ queries will result in same SQL query generated (well, order of LEFT OUTER JOINS may differ). But there will be small performance difference on query generation, because when you are including some path, new `ObjectQuery` will be generated (yes, each `Include` creates new query instead of modifying existing one).

**NOTE:** It was interesting to know why there is no difference - I did some investigation on Entity Framework 6 sources and found the way how EF collects paths which should be included. There is internal sealed class `Span` which holds collection of paths to determine which elements are included into a query. `SpanPath` is really simple - it's just a wrapper on list of strings, which represent navigations to be included:

```
internal class SpanPath
{
    // you can think naviagations as path splitted by dots
    public readonly List<string> Navigations;
    // ...
}
```

And `Span` is a class which holds all included paths:

```
internal sealed class Span
{
    private readonly List<SpanPath> _spanList = new List<SpanPath>();

    public void Include(string path)
    {
        Check.NotEmpty(path, "path");
        SpanPath spanPath = new SpanPath(ParsePath(path));
        this.AddSpanPath(spanPath);
    }

    internal void AddSpanPath(SpanPath spanPath)
    {
        if (this.ValidateSpanPath(spanPath))
        {
            this.RemoveExistingSubPaths(spanPath);
            this._spanList.Add(spanPath);
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateSpanPath(SpanPath spanPath)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this._spanList.Count; i++) 
        {           
            if (spanPath.IsSubPath(this._spanList[i]))                
               return false;    
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

So, here is what happens - when you include new path, then:

1. It is splitted into list of strings and wrapped into SpanPath
2. If current path is sub-path of some already added path, then we just ignore it
3. Otherwise we check if there sub-path of current path exists in our navigations. If so, we remove all sub-paths
4. Now we can add new path.

When you are including `Appointment.Provider.Address` path in first case, then `Appointment` path will be removed on step #3, because it is sub-path of `Appointment.Provider.Address`.

**SUMMARY**:

Do not explicitly include sub-path in query - it will cause in new ObjectQuery instance creation, and it will not affect generated query. It will be either ignored, or it will be removed when you'll add path which includes this one.

Comment: @Sampath welcome :) I did little investigation and posted results. I think it will be interesting to you

Comment: It's really interesting.Thanks for that.But can you tell me, did you use any Tool for investigate the 'SpanPath',etc. details on EF ?

Comment: @Sampath sources of EF available on [codeplex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/Span.cs) but you always can use tools like Reflector to investigate assemblies

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergey.I'll check that. :)